# Почему выдаёт ошибку Chrome failed to start?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#open spotify
driver.get('https://partner.spotify.com/mts-ru/trial6m?code=ef5dc4ea-41bb-4ab5-a3dd-b6ead274c800')

#sign in with Facebook
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn-black.btn--no-margin.btn--full-width').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-block.btn-facebook.ng-binding').click()

#sign in

#username
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('')
#passwod
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
```

Выдаёт вот такое:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown erгor: Chrone failed to start: exited abnoгmally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDr ive г is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (Driver info: chromedr iver-2.42.591071 (0ь695ff80972сс1а65а5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform-Linux 5.4.0-1 029-aws x86_64)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Сделал как вы и просили

Comment: Лучше всю трассу выкладывать :) Поискал `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` и нашел кое-что в https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725918/5909792